# JSON Parser Python Script Issues

Tags: python, json, debugging, error-handling

I'm a first year student in CS, attempting to debug a simple Python script.

The script is attempting to parse a directory of JSON files, aka an AWS bucket. I can't figure out where these errors come from, however:

```
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint

jsonDirectory = "/path/to/dir/"
targetRegion = "-insert-region-here"

print("Searching for records with AWS Region: " + targetRegion)
print("")

for filename in os.listdir(jsonDirectory):
print("Reading: " + filename)
data = json.dumps(open(jsonDirectory + filename))

for i in range(len(data["Records"])):
    if data["Records"][i]["awsRegion"] == targetRegion:
        print("---------------------------")
        print("Record #" + str(i))
        print("Username: " + data["Records"][i]["userIdentity"]    ["userName"])
        print("Event name: " + data["Records"][i]["eventName"])
        print("Event time: " + data["Records"][i]["eventTime"])
        print("---------------------------")

print("")

print("Completed reading files.")
```

The errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/path/to/file.py", line 13, in 
>       data = json.dumps(open(jsonDirectory + filename))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 231, in dumps
>       return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
>       chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
>       return _iterencode(o, 0)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
>       o.**class**.**name**)
>   TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable

Comment: should use `json.load` instead of `json.dumps`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting errors though: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/of/script.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = json.load(open(jsonDirectory + filename))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 37: invalid start byte"

Comment: So it worked for you?

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting.

Comment: check your file, you have an error like indicated in position 37

Comment: Thanks- what do you mean? I don't understand the error message

Comment: **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 37: invalid start byte"** that's the error. You have an issue in position 37

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you are not in Western Europe or USA and the default encoding is not `UTF-8` or something usually very compatible like `iso-8859-1`. From the comments above

```
data = json.load(open(jsonDirectory + filename))
```

If you separate that statement in:

```
f = open(jsonDirectory + filename)
fdata = f.read()
data = json.loads(fdata)
```

You will see that the error happens in `fdata = f.read()`. The suggestion is to do:

```
f = open(jsonDirectory + filename, encoding='my-encoding')
fdata = f.read()
data = json.loads(fdata)
```

If you are unsure, try to force `open` to ignore/bypass the errors. From the Python docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

> errors is an optional string that specifies how encoding and decoding errors are to be handled—this cannot be used in binary mode. A variety of standard error handlers are available (listed under Error Handlers), though any error handling name that has been registered with codecs.register_error() is also valid. The standard names include:
>
> - 'strict' to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.
> - 'ignore' ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.
> - 'replace' causes a replacement marker (such as '?') to be inserted where there is malformed data.
> - 'surrogateescape' will represent any incorrect bytes as code points in the Unicode Private Use Area ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. These private code points will then be turned back into the same bytes when the surrogateescape error handler is used when writing data. This is useful for processing files in an unknown encoding.
> - 'xmlcharrefreplace' is only supported when writing to a file. Characters not supported by the encoding are replaced with the appropriate XML character reference &#nnn;.
> - 'backslashreplace' replaces malformed data by Python’s backslashed escape sequences.
> - 'namereplace' (also only supported when writing) replaces unsupported characters with \N{...} escape sequences.

Start with `ignore` as in:

```
f = open(jsonDirectory + filename, errors='ignore')
fdata = f.read()
data = json.loads(fdata)
```

And check if the output satisfies you or where things have gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I'm still getting encoding/decoding errors, however.

Comment: It's difficult to conceive how you may be facing encoding errors if pass 'ignore' or one of the options that performs replacement (try `errors='replace'`). Further traces could bring more light to the overall picture.